# my phone is asking for a previous google account after reset

Tags: alcatel-one-touch-idol-s

i reset my alcatel one touch and now it wants the previous google account to continue after I reset it and I don't know it how do I get passed this plz help so annoying

Comment: Press 'skip' or similar?

Comment: Hi! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Did you thoroughly search/research for an answer before asking your question?  Tell us [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far and why it didn't meet your needs? This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself and it saves us from reiterating obvious answers.

Answer (score -2):

Go to youtube and look for this video. It'll show you how to bypass Google's FRP Security. Take it from me, I had the same problem but this method actually worked on my Alcatel Acquire+ from At&t.

[image][image]

Comment: They might not know the credentials, and as such this would be useless

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)